# Dynamic adding child routes to lazy loaded module in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular11

I'm developing a modular kind of framework for my employer. So that our customers can say which of the features they want. So I split everything in libraries and added a routing module for each of it.
One of the libraries is the Navigation. It contains a component with a side-bar and a toolbar and the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for its children.

So currently my `AppRoutingModule` looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard, NavigationComponent } from '@company/navigation';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: NavigationComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {
            breadcrumb: null,
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'profile',
                loadChildren: () => import('@company/profile').then((m) => m.ProfileModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'order',
                loadChildren: () => import('@company/endeavour').then((m) => m.OrderModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'user-administration',
                loadChildren: () => import('@company/user-administration').then((m) => m.UserAdministrationModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                loadChildren: () => import('@company/dashboard').then((m) => m.DashboardModule),
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: 'auth',
        loadChildren: () => import('@company/auth').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected' })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

So basically I'm setting the empty route to be my `NavigationComponent` with an `AuthGuard` and set its children to be the lazy loaded modules from the other libraries.

My idea now is that I also add a `NavigationRoutingModule` to my navigation library

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from '@company/shared';
import { NavigationComponent } from '../components/navigation/navigation.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: NavigationComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {
            breadcrumb: null,
        },
        children: [],
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class NavigationRoutingModule {}
```

and reduce the `AppRoutingModule` to something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('@company/navigation').then((m) => m.NavigationModule),
    },
    {
        path: 'auth',
        loadChildren: () => import('@company/auth').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected' })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And then, with some kind of sorcery, I end up with a `NavigationModule` imported in the `AppModule` with some configs passed to the `forRoot()` method of the `NavigationModule` so I can set the routes for this projects.

So my basic idea is, that I have a navigation module with dynamic child routes which get configured through some mechanism. I mean obviously I can't just statically provide all child routes in the `NavigationRoutingModule`. That just would defeat the purpose of the modularity.

Is something like this possible or am I just overthinking it and my current solution is already good?

Comment: how did you get on with this? I'm aiming to accomplish something similar, I have some static routes which are lazy loaded, and some extra dynamic routes to add in there...

Comment: @AdamMarshall have you figured this out? I have some static routes in a lazy-loaded module and need to dynamically add other child routes to the static ones

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly you can can use ROUTES InjectionToken and instead of passing routes directly in the forRoot/forChild function of the RouterModule, just pass an empty array and instead provide the ROUTES token in the providers section. In that case the Angular router will automatically use the routes from the provided token.

For example,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forChild([])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ROUTES,
      useFactory: (appSettings: AppSettings) => {
        const defaultTab: string = appSettings.APP_VERSION === APP_VERSIONS.NL ? 'tab1' : 'tab2';
        const routes: Routes = [
          {
            path: '',
            component: TabsPage,
            children: [
             ...
            ]
          },
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: defaultTab,
            pathMatch: 'full'
          }
        ];
        return routes;
      },
      deps: [
        APP_SETTINGS
      ],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```